# Combined NTFS Permissions & Combined Share Permissions

Tags: permissions, ntfs, file-permissions

Can someone please clarify: What happens to combined NTFS permissions? Does the most restrictive permission prevail or the least restrictive permission wins?

Is this the same to the combined share permissions?

I understand that when combining share and NTFS permissions the most restrictive permission wins. But I am confused by when each combines on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean how user is granted access when there are both allow and deny permissions in place at the same time. It's not as simple as one might think. In your case, take a look at section number four. Here is NTFS permission precedence rules from [NTFS.com](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-precedence.htm):

> Here are some rules for resolving permissions conflicts:
>
> 1. "Deny" permissions generally take precedence over "allow" permissions.
> 2. Permissions applied directly to an object (explicit permissions) take precedence over permissions inherited from a parent (for example from a group).
> 3. Permissions inherited from near relatives take precedence over permissions inherited from distant predecessors. So permissions inherited from the object's parent folder take precedence over permissions inherited from the object's "grandparent" folder, and so on.
> 4. Permissions from different user groups that are at the same level (in terms of being directly-set or inherited, and in terms of being "deny" or "allow") are cumulative. So if a user is a member of two groups, one of which has an "allow" permission of "Read" and the other has an "allow" of "Write", the user will have both read and write permission--depending on the other rules above, of course.
>
> Although Deny permissions generally take precedence over allow permissions, this is not always the case. An explicit "allow" permission can take precedence over an inherited "deny" permission.
>
> The hierarchy of precedence for the permissions can be summarized as follows, with the higher precedence permissions listed at the top of the list:
>
> Explicit Deny
>
> Explicit Allow
>
> Inherited Deny
>
> Inherited Allow
>
> Also true:
> File permissions override folder permissions, unless the Full Control permission has been granted to the folder.

About share permissions (mentioned by @Twisty Impersonator):

The same rules apply to share permissions. Note that there's no concept of inheritance in share permissions since the user gains access to a share via a single point of access, namely the share.

Comment: I read this online too, it does not answer my question. I don't mean deny & allow conflicting, my confusion is on: when different levels of "allows" (such as read on one, modify on another) occur at once, which one prevails? The most restrictive one or the least restrictive one?

Comment: The user is part of two groups. One allows the user to read and the other allows the user to modify. Is this the case? Then both read and modify are allowed, since there is no conflict. This case is specified in the section number four. Only denying (explicitly or inherited) would restrict the user from reading or modifying the file.

Comment: Aka. The least restrictive permission wins, yes? Does this apply to share permissions too?

Comment: One might say that, yes. But remember, that is not always the case. I would think that the same rules apply to share permissions as well, although I didn't find any proof. I can try it when I have some time.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen The same rules apply to share permissions. Note that there's no concept of inheritance in share permissions since the user gains access to a share via a single point of access, namely the share.

Comment: Thank you, @TwistyImpersonator! With your permission (no pun intended), I would like to add this to my answer.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen please do. I'll "Allow" that! LOL.